# How to paginate the query results when using Laravel eloquent relationships

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent-relationship

I have the following query which retrieves the child configuration records (confch) associated with the parent configuration (confp) and it works fine.

```
$data["items"] = Confp::find(decrypt($type))->Confch;
```

I just need to paginate the results.

adding `->paginate(10)` would definitly not work as it does not exist in the resulting collection. I found nothing helping in the laravel documentation.

How can I do that please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of above code.

```
$confp = Confp::find(decrypt($type));
$data["items"] = $confp->setRelation('Confch',$confp->Confch()->paginate(10));
```